# Avoid email preference center in Pardot

Tags: email-template, landing-page, pardot, unsubscriber

We're using a custom preference center based on an external landing page. We want to remove or replace the default links in email footer to the required default email preference center

How to replace/remove the default links with custom links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i have done is assign the link to a dummy preference page to a "period" character and made that in white font and 1 pixel in height. There is no way to completely remove it but this minimizes the chance of someone opening it up. If by chance, someone ever clicked on it, the form that it links to has an auto redirect in the template html code so it will redirect to the correct email preference form. Its a bit of a hack!

Answer (score 0):

It's mandatory to offer marketing email recipients an unsubscribe link or a Pardot preference page containing an unsubscribe link. As long as you keep the unsubscribe option in your email template, you may use an external preferences page.

To remove the default link, and point to your external landing page you simply edit the email template. See example below.

[image]